# Compactness and ordinals.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Source:Conover **A First Course In Topology**

I have started studying compactness.
This is not homework

**Prove that the space of countable ordinals
[$0$,$\Omega$) is not compact ,but [$0$,$\Omega$] is compact.**

I have this theorem

**Theorem 5.9**
Any countable subset of [$0$,$\Omega$) is bounded above.

**My try**

As to the first part,
[$0$,$\Omega$) is uncountable but by 5.9 we can find finite sub cover cause it’s bounded above. Contradiction. Thus not
compact

As to the second part I am clueless how to
do it.

I only have the def of compactness and
Heine-Borel theorem to go on .

Out of curiosity,would I have to do a proof like Prop 3
(Page 5 of 29)
[Ordinal Compactness by Lipparini](https://www.pmf.ni.ac.rs/filomat-content/2020/34-4/34-4-7-1560.pdf) ?

I feel so dumb…

I would like see the solution,if possible.
Thanks

Comment: "we can find finite sub cover cause it's bounded above" What is the cover that you're trying to find a finite subcover of?

Comment: That argument for the first part is not correct. You should give a open cover that doesn't have a finite subcover. For example $\{[0,x)\}_{x\in[0,\Omega)}$.

Comment: For the second part, assume that $\{U_n\}$ is some open cover. Let $U_{m}$ be some element of the cover that contains $\Omega$. Then it should contain some interval $(a,\Omega)$. There must be elements $U_{n_k}$ of the cover that contain $k$, for $k=0,1,3,...,a$. Since $a$ is finite, then $\{U_{n_k}\}_{k=0,1,...,a}\cup\{U_{m}\}$ is a finite cover of $[0,\Omega]$.

Comment: @Boxwood Then it is not compact. I can’t think of any other examples in the ordinals

Comment: Yes, $[0,\Omega)$ is not compact. Compactness is a condition about open covers. the intervals $[1,x)$ are not open and they don't cover $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your attempted proof of the first part (that $[0, \Omega)$ is not compact) does not make any sense at all. You need to propose a specific open cover of $[0, \Omega)$ and then prove that this open cover does not admit a finite subcover.

For the second part, we actually don't need to know anything about $\Omega$ other than that it's an ordinal. You should consider an arbitrary open cover $U$ of $[0, \Omega]$. Let $S = \{x \in [0, \Omega] : $ for no $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n \in U$ is it the case that $[0, x] \subseteq U_1 \cup U_2 \cup \cdots \cup U_n\}$. Suppose that there is no finite subcover of $U$. Then $\Omega \in S$. Since $S$ is a nonempty set of ordinals, it must have a least element $\xi$. Now take some $K \in U$ such that $\xi \in K$. Then take some $(a, b) \subseteq U$ such that $a < \xi < b$. Then since $a < \xi$, we must have $a \notin S$, and therefore there is some $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n \in U$ such that $[0, a] \subseteq U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n$. But then $[0, \xi] \subseteq U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n \cup U$, which contradicts the claim that $\xi \in S$.

Comment: Ok ,I am new to it and with ordinals it gives me the heebee geebies

Answer (score 0):

An open proper subset of $\Omega$ need not be bounded above in $[0,\Omega)$ so if $C$ is an open cover of $[0,\Omega)$ then $\cup C$\ need not be bounded above either.

Let $C=\Omega=\{x: x\in\Omega\}=\{[0,x):x\in \Omega\}.$ Then $C$ is an open cover of $\Omega=[0,\Omega).$ If $D$ is a non-empty finite subset of $C$ then $\bar x=\max D$ exists and $\bar x\in \Omega$ but $\bar x\not\in \bar x=\cup D.$

If $Y$ is a set of ordinals then the ordinal $\cup Y$ is the lub for $Y.$ If $X$ is a successor ordinal (that is, if $\max X$ exists) and if $Y\subseteq X$ then $\cup Y\in X.$ In particular when $X=[0,\Omega]=\Omega +1.$

Theorem. Let $X$ be  non-empty and linearly ordered by  $<$. Then every $Y\subseteq X$ has a $<$-lub in $X$ iff  the $<$-order topology on $X$ is compact.

Remarks: $\{x+1: x\in\Omega \}$ is an unbounded open subset of $\Omega.$ Its closed complement $\{x\in\Omega: x=\cup x\}$ in the space $\Omega$ is also unbounded in $\Omega$ .... Many set-theorists use $\omega$ for the least infinite ordinal and use $\omega_1$ for $\Omega.$

Comment: I can’t use that theorem. I can use Heine-Borel theorem and the definition and basic stuff on ordinals

Comment: If every $Y\subseteq X$ has a $lub$ then $\max X=lub (X)$ exists and $\min X=lub (\emptyset)$ exists. Now a kind of Heine-Borel argument  shows $X$ is compact: Let $C$ be an open cover of $X.$  Let $Y\subseteq X$ where $y\in Y$ iff a finite subset of $C$ covers $[\min X,y]$.Clearly $\min X\in Y.$  And if $y\in Y$ then $[\min X,y]\subseteq Y.$  Now show that $lub (Y)\in Y$ and then show by contradiction that $lub (Y)=\max X.$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the theorem that if $X$ is an ordered space in the order topology, then

> $X$ is compact iff it’s order complete and has a maximum and minimum. Also quotable as "iff every subset of $X$ has a sup and inf" (note that $\sup \emptyset= \min X$ etc.)

As $[0,\Omega)$ has no maximum it is not compact ( it *is* order complete though) while $[0,\Omega]$ does satisfy both conditions.

The above theorem also shows that the subsets $[a,b]$ of the reals are compact. It’s a classic theorem from the fifties or older. Not too many books cover it though, which is a shame.

Comment: Do you mean Theorem 5.9? I thought [0,$\Omega$) had no max cause it is half open and the other is closed. I was born in 1962

Comment: @HomerSimpson theorem 5.9 where? It has no max cause it’s a limit ordinal.

Comment: You mean X is compact iff it is order complete and has max and min. I thought you mention any countable subset of [0,$\Omega$) is bounded above

Comment: @HomerSimpson the countable set property is irrelevant for compactness. It does show countable compactness.